# how to duplicate a row n number of times based on column?

Tags: excel

my boss asks me to generate a report for employees tickets each month. he then asks me to duplicate the rows in the same amount of the tickets. I realize this is not very intuitive but that's what he asks.
the file I generate is like this

Employee | Number of tickets
emp1 | 2
emp2 | 4
emp3 | 1

the way the output needs to be is:

emp1 | 2
emp1 | 2
emp2 | 4
emp2 | 4
emp2 | 4
emp2 | 4
emp3 | 1

of course for small numbers I can simply copy paste the rows in the amount of tickets but the tickets are now over 100 which takes a long time to copy past manually. is there a way I can run a script that duplicates the rows based on tickets automatically?

Answer (score 0):

I found the script using this https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4054-excel-duplicate-rows-based-on-cell-value.html

```js
Sub CopyData()
'Updateby Extendoffice 20160922
    Dim xRow As Long
    Dim VInSertNum As Variant
    xRow = 1
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Do While (Cells(xRow, "A") <> "")
        VInSertNum = Cells(xRow, "D")
        If ((VInSertNum > 1) And IsNumeric(VInSertNum)) Then
           Range(Cells(xRow, "A"), Cells(xRow, "D")).Copy
           Range(Cells(xRow + 1, "A"), Cells(xRow + VInSertNum - 1, "D")).Select
           Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
           xRow = xRow + VInSertNum - 1
        End If
        xRow = xRow + 1
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub
```

all I needed was replacing the "D" with the column of the number of tickets and it worked.